# Conditional for user registration fields

Tags: plugin-development, users, plugins, registration, usermodel

What’s the best way to validate a user registration form to make sure that at least one of two fields is not empty?

I’ve tried a very simple controller but can’t get this to work past the point of trying to save the user. Any pointers with this method or for a different method entirely?

```
public function actionIndex() {

    $this->requirePostRequest();

    $fields = craft()->request->getPost('fields');

    $customField1 = $fields['customField1'];
    $customField2 = $fields['customField2'];

    $user = new UserModel();
    $user->email = craft()->request->getPost('email');
    $user->password = craft()->request->getPost('password');
    $user->setContentFromPost('fields');

    if ($customField1 != '' || $customField2 != '') {

        // RETURN CUSTOM ERROR

    }

    // OTHERWISE SUBMIT USER REGISTRATION REQUEST 
    // AND RETURN ANY ERRORS

    craft()->users->saveUser($user);
    $this->redirectToPostedUrl();

}
```

Comment: What if you changed the `&&` (and) to an `||` (or). So your statement would now be `if customField` is not empty OR customField2 is not empty`...

Comment: @Damon good spot but it was a typo with the example, sorry. Edited the question. The validation part works it seems to be the saveUser part here that’s not checking out.

Comment: James, please re-read Damon's suggestion, I think it should in fact solve your problem. And @Damon, I think you should add it as a proper answer?!

Comment: @carlcs the conditional is not the problem here. I didn’t set the example properly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I needed to set `$user->username = craft()->request->getPost('email');` for my attempt to work.